# Integrating FaceTime functionality into iPad app

Tags: ios, ipad, facetime

My company is planning develop an iPad app that will rely heavily on video calls and I am trying to decide which API/tools to use.

Our requirements are as follows:

- High quality video with minimal delay or dropping of calls (provided users on each end have good connection)
- Good security
- Customizable UI; ability to move/resize video windows
- Ability to switch between FaceTime and iSight cameras; user would typically use FaceTime but could turn iPad around to use iSight when better resolution is required

I am well aware that there is no FaceTime API.  Is there some other WebRTC-like API/SDK I could use that meets these requirements?  Based on my research so far, OpenTok (TokBox) seems like the best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AddLive is another API, though at this point, it seems incomplete. It is missing files from iOS SDK at least as of today.

Comment: The AddLive SDK is still invitation-only. We still want to know every customer to understand their needs and how we can help. More info: http://www.addlive.com/; Request access: http://www.addlive.com/request/